# How to change width of tabs in jQuery Steps Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, jquery-steps

I am using [jQuerySteps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples) Plugin to create tabs. I have four section and thus 4 tabs and they work prefectly fine. But I want each tab to have `different percent of width`. As of now each of them gets 25%. But I want to manually assign them the width. I can do it by adding CSS class. But since it's a plugin I am not able to find how the `<ul> and <li>` are getting created and rendered.

Here is how the plugin is setting 25% width.[image]

**My front end code:**

```
<div id="example-basic">
    <h3>Keyboard</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Effects</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Pager</h3>
    <section>
        <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
$("#example-basic").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true
});
```

**Question:**

How to add id or class so that I can set width of `first tab : 20 % second tab:40 % and so on`

Comment: You could also use like .wizard>.steps>ul>li:nth-child(1),.wizard>.steps>ul>li:nth-child(2)

Comment: It worked. Can you add it as an answer. I will accept it. It will help others too.

Comment: Plz send fiddle so I can set here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS

```
.wizard>.steps>ul>li:nth-child(1){
    width: 20%;
}
.wizard>.steps>ul>li:nth-child(2){
    width: 40%;
}
```